# Можно ли сделать какой то процесс фоновым?

Tags: python

Когда я делал свою "игру" у меня появилась потребность сделать что бы пока создаются слитки, могла работать функция, например сейчас у меня есть идея попробовать сделать какую-то мини-игру что бы создавать слитки было не так скучно

```
import time
n = 0 #Количество

s = 200 #сырьё из которого делают слитки
c = 0 #слитки

n = int(input("  Выберите количество слитков которые вы хотите произвести.\n"))
while c < n:
    time.sleep(1)
    c = c+1
    s = s-1
    print("  Слитков +1")
    print("  Всего слитков")
    print (c)
```

Надеюсь всё указал, знаю что можно было сделать проще, но оно работает и это главное. Так вот, суть в том что я пытался сделать что бы это работало на фоне, но ничего похожего не нашёл, буду очень благодарен если кто то поможет.

Comment: почитайте про потоки и синхронизацию (например, https://webdevblog.ru/vvedenie-v-potoki-v-python/)

Answer (score 0):

[Asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) советую ознакомиться с этим.

Также для лучшего понимания можно прочитать вот эту статью - [Асинхронный python без головной боли](https://habr.com/ru/post/667630/).

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос. либо [оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)